# Camel NotifyBuilder always returns false

Tags: java, apache-camel

I've got a fairly simple route:

**PerfStubRouteBuilder.java**

```
public class PerfStubRouteBuilder extends SpringRouteBuilder {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder#configure()
     */
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("direct:test-aces-input")
        .log("Creating test Accident Number header")
        .setHeader("AccidentNumber", simple("AB999999999"))
        .log("Test Accident Number header created : ${header.AccidentNumber}")
        .end();
    }
}
```

and I'm testing it as follows:

**PerfStubRouteBuilderTest.java**

```
public class PerfStubRouteBuilderTest extends CamelTestSupport {
    @Produce(uri = "direct:test-aces-input")
    ProducerTemplate template;

    PerfStubRouteBuilder route = new PerfStubRouteBuilder();
    Exchange exch = new DefaultExchange(context);

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
        return route;
    }

    @Test
    public void test_PerfStubRouteBuilder_happyPath_addsAccidentNumberHeaderToExchange() throws Exception {
        startCamelContext();
        NotifyBuilder notify = new NotifyBuilder(context).from("direct:test-aces-input").whenDone(1).filter(header("AccidentNumber").isEqualTo("AB999999999")).create();
        template.send(exch);
        assertTrue(notify.matches(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        stopCamelContext();
    }
}
```

assertTrue always come back as false, so I suspect I'm not using the NotifyBuilder correctly although at this point I can't be certain. Essentially I want to check that an exchange makes it through the route and the header specified in the actual route is added to the exchange. What I want to happen is for a match to occur if an exchange with that header value combo makes it to the end of the route, hence the filter step. I want to avoid adding an endpoint at the end of the route, for example, via AdviceWith given how small and simple the route itself is , it seems a bit heavyweight to start adding in mock endpoints for such a minor test

**UPDATE:**

Tried removing the filter portion from the expression, leaving the NotifyBuilder as `NotifyBuilder notify = new NotifyBuilder(context).from("direct:test-aces-input").whenDone(1).create();`
 , the test still fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the exchange from the endpoint in the test like

```
Endpoint endpoint = context.getEndpoint("direct:test-aces-input");
Exchange exchange = endpoint.createExchange();
template.send(exchange);
```

or just directly use sendBody

```
tempalte.sendBody("")
```

Comment: Excellent, worked first time. Is there some sort of issue with using a default exchange with NotifyBuilder?

Comment: Its this comment here https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/5cdc8ae7e28113f127dfe637460fd4a047623463/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/builder/NotifyBuilder.java#L191

Comment: `sendBody` did not work for me (I'm in the context of a spring-boot-application), but sending the `exchange` created from the endpoint works fine.