# Camel NotifyBuilder condition fails

Tags: java, apache-camel

I had a similar problem with a slightly simpler route:
[Camel NotifyBuilder always returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46730276/camel-notifybuilder-always-returns-false)

My route is as follows:

**PerfTestRouteBuilder**

```
@Component
public class PerfTestRouteBuilder extends SpringRouteBuilder {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder#configure()
     */
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("direct:test-input")
        .log("Creating test response object")
        .process(exchange -> {
            WOutputAccnLayout stubResponse = new WOutputAccnLayout();
            stubResponse.setWOutAccnAccNum("AB999999999");
            stubResponse.setWOutAccnCallStatus("SUCCESS");
            exchange.getIn().setBody(stubResponse, WOutputAccnLayout.class);
        })
        .log("Test response object created: ${body}")
        .end();
    }
}
```

And I have the following test:

**PerfTestRouteBuilderIT**

```
public class PerfTestRouteBuilderIT extends CamelTestSupport {

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
        return new PerfTestRouteBuilder();
    }

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
    }

    @Test
    public void test_configure_exchangeSentToTestRoute_stubResponseAddedToBody() throws Exception {
        startCamelContext();
        NotifyBuilder notify  = new NotifyBuilder(context)
                .from("direct:test-input")
                .whenAnyDoneMatches(body().isEqualTo(getStubResponse()))
                .create();

        template.sendBody("direct:test-input", "");

        assertThat(notify.matches(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS), is(true));

        stopCamelContext();
    }

    private WOutputAccnLayout getStubResponse() {
        WOutputAccnLayout stubResponse = new WOutputAccnLayout();
        stubResponse.setWOutAccnAccNum("AB999999999");
        stubResponse.setWOutAccnCallStatus("SUCCESS");
        return stubResponse;
    }

}
```

The condition always evaluates as false and I don't see why, considering the getStubResponse method returns an object set up exactly like it would be in the route. The solution last time was to use template.sendBody, or create an exchange via the route endpoint and use it and neither approach has worked thus far. Is it something around how I'm using the camel test kit?

Comment: Is it maybe the .equals() implementation of WOutputAccnLayout  object?

Comment: good point, will look into it

Comment: Yep, tried an assertEquals on the body and the stub response, failed due to how .equals is implemented. Unfortunately its a generated class so i cant change the equals implementation but at least i know its not the notifybuilder

Answer (score 0):

as per Itsallas' comment, issue was down to .equals implementation for object used in assertion